# CoffeeScript in index.html

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

My index.html file doesn't see the

```
<script type="text/coffeescript"></script>
```

I mean, I have `text/javascript`, `text/ecmascript` and etc, but there not the `text/coffeescript`. How can I connect CoffeeScript in index.html, and why brackets does not see type of CoffeeScript?

Comment: Browser can't compile coffeescript. You need to compile it to javascript yourself.

Comment: how can I do this?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://coffeescript.org/#usage)